# In Spark, how to repartition large data frames/RDDs such that shuffling while joining is reduced as much as possible?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one table called **A** which has a column called **id**. I have another table called **B** which has a column called **a_id** which refers to table **A**'s **id** column (foreign key). I want to join these two tables based on this column but both the table are quite large (The size of table A is ~ 1 TB and table B is ~ 4.2 TB). So, my plan is to reduce shuffling as much as possible to increase efficiency, and for that, I am trying to partition the data frames such that rows with the same value in the two columns reside in the same partition as in the following example.

**Example tables:**

```
A: 
id  category
1   tennis
2   cricket

B:
name   a_id
Roger  1
Novak  1
Lara   2
Ricky  2
```

**What I want to achieve after partition:**

```
Partition 1:
A: 
id  category
1   tennis

B:
name   a_id
Roger  1
Novak  1

Partition 2:
A: 
id  category
2   cricket

B:
name   a_id
Lara   2
Ricky  2
```

I was trying to achieve this by repartitioning **A** on column **id** and repartitioning **B** on column **a_id** after loading the tables. I checked this on a short test dataset and it seemed to render what I want.

But on the full dataset, spark job does a lot of shuffling during joining and gets stuck. So, what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I think you should check bucketing and see if that helps.

Comment: @Nikunj, Thanks for your answer. I read a few articles on bucketing and it seems like it requires hive which I don't have. Does bucketing work without hive?